# How to do z transform using python sympy?

Tags: python, signal-processing, sympy

z transform is very important in signal process. I can find fourier, laplace, cosine transform and so on in sympy tutorial. But I do not know how to do z transform using sympy. Could you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Looks like it is simply [not implemented in sympy](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/587184c69d08ec08df19adced3cfb8a654353dae/sympy/core/tests/test_wester.py#L2986-L2995).

Comment: not symbolic but: [module-scipy.signal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/signal.html#module-scipy.signal)

Comment: there has been open issue since one day after this question was asked: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12502

Answer (score 1):

SymPy doesn't have it implemented as a transform function yet, but you can represent the summations directly. However, after some playing with it, it looks it is limited in what sums it can actually compute. Here's an example of one that works:

```
>>> pprint(summation(n*z**-n, (n, -oo, oo)))
⎧      z           1           │1│
⎪- ───────── + ──────────  for │─│ < 1 ∧ │z│ < 1
⎪          2            2      │z│
⎪  (-z + 1)      ⎛    1⎞
⎪              z⋅⎜1 - ─⎟
⎪                ⎝    z⎠
⎪
⎨        ∞
⎪       ___
⎪       ╲
⎪        ╲      -n
⎪        ╱   n⋅z                 otherwise
⎪       ╱
⎪       ‾‾‾
⎩      False
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice package (lcapy) which is based on sympy but can do z transform and inverse and a lot more other time discrete stuff.

https://pypi.org/project/lcapy/

Simply try

```
import lcapy as lc
from lcapy.discretetime import n

xk=n*2**n*lc.exp(3j*n)
X0=xk.ZT()
print(X0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added two comments with code examples on how to get the transform here, note they don't always work.

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12502